# How to setup Redis cluster behind a load balancer?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

We want to set up Redis 6.2 clustering behind a LB. There are only master nodes and there is no Redis Sentinel being used. **Each cluster-enabled Redis instance is running on a different host with the same configuration** (eg. all of them are configured with port 6379). Is this possible with some port configuration on the LB such that a unique port on an LB maps to a unique_ip:6379?

Our idea is to use a cluster-aware Redis client like Lettuce RedisClusterClient which would issue CLUSTER NODES/SLOTS commands or react to MOVED/ASK redirection. It would also take care of split up a pipeline into using separate connections based on the slot for a command

It seems like this is not possible to achieve if the same port is used on all Redis hosts. Using https://docs.redis.com/latest/rs/networking/cluster-lba-setup/ as a guide, the best we could manage was to configure each Redis with a unique port and set cluster-announce-ip as the virtual IP (points to LB) and then manually make sure that the same port is used on LB as the Redis host. With this, the CLUSTER SLOTS and MOVED responses from Redis hosts could be correctly acted upon by the client. But this complicates our setup when a new Redis host has to be added or removed

Answer (score 0):

You can use Route 53 if you're on AWS to achieve this.

Create A setup like this:

Add all hosts(IP addresses) in Route 53 and set TTL to smaller values like 30 seconds or so. Route 53 will return one of these Redis IP addresses, using this endpoint Redis clients like Lettuce or Jedis will discover all the Redis nodes.

You can use any other DNS system as well, record type should be A.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @sonus21. What we are trying to achieve is to hide the actual ip addresses of the Redis servers. Instead we want Redis cluster-aware clients to connect to a load-balancer VIP on a specific port. The load-balancer configuration needs to be such that incoming traffic to a specific port should be forwarded to a specific backend Redis server. (The client is already aware of which port to use for which slot)

Comment: Using LB you're hiding IP from the client but the client will send commands to find all the node addresses. We're doing the same using DNS as we're doing using LB.

Comment: So what we are trying to achieve is that client should not be able to find out node addresses. For eg. in response to a CLUSTER NODES command, client should see <LB VIP>:<lbport1>, <LB VIP>:<lbport2> etc. instead of <IP1>:6379, <IP2>:6379 etc. We are basically trying to force all traffic via the LB for TLS termination or other compliance